# swap windows with dash script

Tags: ubuntu, window, kubuntu, dash

I have written a bunch of dash scripts that resize and move windows for better efficiency.

The structure is the following: i have a row of 8 windows that are stacked to the bottom of my screen, like thumbnails if you will. Let's call each of those windows miniportal_1,...,miniportal_8

When i want to work with one of them a script resizes it above the row so that it occupies the remaining part of the screen and becomes mainportal

To better visualize, the concept is inspired by the fighter jet F-35 displays ([See image](http://bbs.replays.net/upload/2009/10/29/1639/15926240629184.jpg))

What i want to do is that if there's already one mainportal present, the miniportal window that i resize replaces it but also that the mainportal window is resized and moved to the former miniportal image. So in short i want to swap the miniportal and portal windows.

I think what i need to do something like that:

1/store the ID, geometry and coordinates of all visible windows using wmctrl

```
visible_windows_ID_array=wmctrl -l -G | awk '{print S1}'
visible_windows_geometry=same but with different awk option
visible_windows_coordinates= same but with different awk option
```

2/Do a for loop with an if test to get the ID of the mainportal window

```
for((i=0;i<${#get_visible_windows_ID_array[@]}; i++ )) do
```

and this is where i can't find the correct syntax for the If test. I want to do something like that:

```
if visible_windows_geometry[i]= mainportal geometry  && visible_windows_coordinates[i]= mainportal coordinates then
get visible_windows_ID[i]
fi
done
```

Once i have the mainportal window ID i can use wmctrl -r to resize it.

Any idea on how i could do that?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, here is one example finding the ID of a miniportal window already present in case you can to move a portal window back to miniportal and hence switch the miniportal window to portal.

```
function getportalwindowID {
IFS=$'\n'
W=5
H=6
X=3
Y=4
ID=1
windowsID=($(wmctrl -l -G | awk -v ID=$ID  '{print $ID}'))
windowsgeometry_w=($(wmctrl -l -G | awk -v W=$W  '{print $W}'))
windowsgeometry_h=($(wmctrl -l -G | awk -v H=$H  '{print $H}'))
windowscoordinates_x=($(wmctrl -l -G | awk -v X=$X  '{print $X}'))
windowscoordinates_y=($(wmctrl -l -G | awk -v Y=$Y  '{print $Y}'))


for ((i=0; i<${#windowsID[*]}; i++));
do
if [ ${windowsgeometry_h[i]} = 180 ] && [ ${windowsgeometry_w[i]} = 320 ] && [ ${windowscoordinates_x[i]} = $(($activescreendisthorizontal+ 0)) ] && [ ${windowscoordinates_y[i]} = 1260 ]; then

portalwindowid=${windowsID[i]}

echo $portalwindowid

fi

done

}
```